# Azure web job is getting access denied while accessing shared location

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I have shared location on Azure VM and web job in the same Vnet on Azure. I have C# script deployed on webjob to access the shared location. When I execute web job to access it, I am getting bewlo error:

> [03/22/2019 15:02:19 > eb8046: SYS INFO] Status changed to
>   Initializing
>
> [03/22/2019 15:02:29 > eb8046: SYS INFO] Run script
>   'AccessSharedLocation.exe' with script host - 'WindowsScriptHost'
>
> [03/22/2019 15:02:29 > eb8046: SYS INFO] Status changed to Running
>
> [03/22/2019 15:02:32 > eb8046: ERR ]
>
> [03/22/2019 15:02:32 > eb8046: ERR ] Unhandled Exception:
>   System.Net.WebException: Access to the path
>   '\192.168.1.4\shared\nilo.txt' is denied. --->
>   System.Net.WebException: Access to the path
>   '\192.168.1.4\shared\nilo.txt' is denied. --->
>   System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path
>   '\192.168.1.4\shared\nilo.txt' is denied.
>
> [03/22/2019 15:02:32 > eb8046: ERR ]    at
>   System.IO.FileStream.ValidateFileHandle(SafeFileHandle fileHandle)
>
> [03/22/2019 15:02:32 > eb8046: ERR ]    at
>   System.IO.FileStream.CreateFileOpenHandle(FileMode mode, FileShare
>   share, FileOptions options)
>
> [03/22/2019 15:02:32 > eb8046: ERR ]    at
>   System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess
>   access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options)
>
> [03/22/2019 15:02:32 > eb8046: ERR ]    at
>   System.Net.FileWebResponse..ctor(FileWebRequest request, Uri uri,
>   FileAccess access, Boolean useAsync)
>
> [03/22/2019 15:02:32 > eb8046: ERR ]    --- End of inner exception
>   stack trace ---
>
> [03/22/2019 15:02:32 > eb8046: ERR ]    at
>   System.Net.FileWebResponse..ctor(FileWebRequest request, Uri uri,
>   FileAccess access, Boolean useAsync)
>
> [03/22/2019 15:02:32 > eb8046: ERR ]    at
>   System.Net.FileWebRequest.CreateResponse()
>
> [03/22/2019 15:02:32 > eb8046: ERR ]    --- End of inner exception
>   stack trace ---
>
> [03/22/2019 15:02:32 > eb8046: ERR ]    at
>   System.Net.FileWebRequest.CreateResponse()
>
> [03/22/2019 15:02:32 > eb8046: ERR ]    at
>   System.Net.FileWebRequest.<>c.b__59_0(Object s)
>
> [03/22/2019 15:02:32 > eb8046: ERR ]    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
>
> [03/22/2019 15:02:32 > eb8046: ERR ]    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>
> [03/22/2019 15:02:32 > eb8046: ERR ] --- End of stack trace from
>   previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> [03/22/2019 15:02:32 > eb8046: ERR ]    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task&
>   currentTaskSlot)
>
> [03/22/2019 15:02:32 > eb8046: ERR ] --- End of stack trace from
>   previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> [03/22/2019 15:02:32 > eb8046: ERR ]    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskToApm.End[TResult](IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)
>
> [03/22/2019 15:02:32 > eb8046: ERR ]    at
>   System.Net.FileWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>
> [03/22/2019 15:02:32 > eb8046: ERR ]    at
>   System.Net.FileWebRequest.GetResponse()
>
> [03/22/2019 15:02:32 > eb8046: ERR ]    at
>   System.Net.WebClient.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
>
> [03/22/2019 15:02:32 > eb8046: ERR ]    at
>   System.Net.WebClient.OpenRead(Uri address)
>
> [03/22/2019 15:02:32 > eb8046: ERR ]    at
>   AccessSharedLocation.Program.buttonDownloadFile_Click() in
>   C:\Users\dharti.sutariya\source\repos\AccessSharedLocation\AccessSharedLocation\Program.cs:line
>   63
>
> [03/22/2019 15:02:32 > eb8046: ERR ]    at
>   AccessSharedLocation.Program.Main(String[] args) in
>   C:\Users\dharti.sutariya\source\repos\AccessSharedLocation\AccessSharedLocation\Program.cs:line
>   48
>
> [03/22/2019 15:02:32 > eb8046: INFO] Hello World!
>
> [03/22/2019 15:02:32 > eb8046: SYS INFO] Status changed to Failed
>
> [03/22/2019 15:02:32 > eb8046: SYS ERR ] Job failed due to exit code
>   -532462766

**Below is my C# code**

```
using System;

using System.ComponentModel;

using System.Net;

using System.Runtime.InteropServices;



namespace AccessSharedLocation

{

    public class NetworkConnection : IDisposable

    {

        readonly string _networkName;



        public NetworkConnection(string networkName, NetworkCredential credentials)

        {

            _networkName = networkName;



            var netResource = new NetResource

            {

                Scope = ResourceScope.GlobalNetwork,

                ResourceType = ResourceType.Disk,

                DisplayType = ResourceDisplaytype.Share,

                RemoteName = networkName

            };



            var userName = string.IsNullOrEmpty(credentials.Domain)

                ? credentials.UserName

                : string.Format(@"{0}\{1}", credentials.Domain, credentials.UserName);



            var result = WNetAddConnection2(

                netResource,

                credentials.Password,

                userName,

                0);



            if (result != 0)

            {

                throw new Win32Exception(result);

            }

        }



        ~NetworkConnection()

        {

            Dispose(false);

        }



        public void Dispose()

        {

            Dispose(true);

            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);

        }



        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)

        {

            WNetCancelConnection2(_networkName, 0, true);

        }



        [DllImport("mpr.dll")]

        private static extern int WNetAddConnection2(NetResource netResource,

            string password, string username, int flags);



        [DllImport("mpr.dll")]

        private static extern int WNetCancelConnection2(string name, int flags,

            bool force);



        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]

        public class NetResource

        {

            public ResourceScope Scope;

            public ResourceType ResourceType;

            public ResourceDisplaytype DisplayType;

            public int Usage;

            public string LocalName;

            public string RemoteName;

            public string Comment;

            public string Provider;

        }



        public enum ResourceScope : int

        {

            Connected = 1,

            GlobalNetwork,

            Remembered,

            Recent,

            Context

        };



        public enum ResourceType : int

        {

            Any = 0,

            Disk = 1,

            Print = 2,

            Reserved = 8,

        }



        public enum ResourceDisplaytype : int

        {

            Generic = 0x0,

            Domain = 0x01,

            Server = 0x02,

            Share = 0x03,

            File = 0x04,

            Group = 0x05,

            Network = 0x06,

            Root = 0x07,

            Shareadmin = 0x08,

            Directory = 0x09,

            Tree = 0x0a,

            Ndscontainer = 0x0b

        }

    }

}
```

Can anyone please help me out with this. Any help would be great. if this is achievable thorugh Powershell as well, it would work. I have tried several powershell but Azure does not allow to install/execute several module with admin access. The same powershell works with my local system but not through Azure web job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The App Service sandbox explicitly does not allow access to the ports necessary for SMB protocol (137/138/139/445).

This article mentions it under Restricted Outgoing Ports:

https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox.